# Update and retrieve data on Unity using Firebase, performance issue

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to get the gyroscope value of a smartphone and send it to another one. I managed to set a value and retrieve it, however the result is very laggy, is the following method correct?

If no what can I change?

If yes is their another way to set a value and retrieve it in realtime in Unity?

```
//UPDATING THE VALUE
reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
Dictionary<string, object> gyro = new Dictionary<string, object>();
gyro["keyToUpdate"] = valueToUpdate;
reference.Child("parentKey").UpdateChildrenAsync(gyro);

// RETRIEVING THE VALUE
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
.GetReference("parentKey")
.Child("keyToUpdate")
.GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
    if (task.IsFaulted) {
        Debug.Log("error");
    }
    else if (task.IsCompleted) {
    DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
    float valueUpdated = float.Parse(snapshot.Value.ToString());
    Debug.Log(valueUpdated);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is fundamentally slower than you think it is. This is within its performance boundaries.

Comment: Ok that's not a bug then, thanks for the precision, by using sockets do you think I could achieve better results ? (for example using https://github.com/NetEase/UnitySocketIO)

Comment: Yes, but results will be better mostly because you'll be running your own infrastructure. Note that the SocketIO package you found is ancient. Also, SocketIO running in "xhr-polling" mode will be slower than even Firebase, and SocketIO has many configuration landmines. Try straight websockets first (with a websockets package from the Asset Store)

Answer (score 0):

With any asynchronous calls, you can never be sure how fast or slow you may receive a response.  Keep in mind that Firebase is routed through a system which is layered with elements for dealing with things like authentication and decentralized data.

If you continue to use Firebase, you'll need to make sure your code and UI is set up to allow for possibly long delays which are out of your control.  Or you could spend lots of time building your own infrastructure, as [DoctorPangloss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1757994/doctorpangloss) mentioned.